# Работа с файлами Node.js

Tags: node.js, hex

С клиентской машины приходит файл (расширение пусть будет .jpeg). К примеру пережатый фавикон гугла выглядит вот так:

```
DFFDFDFF EFEFEF0E **FFD8**FFFE 00043A29 FFDB0043 00A06E78 8C7864A0 8C828CB4 AAA0BEF0 FFFFF0DC DCF0FFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFDB00 4301AAB4 B4F0D2F0 FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFC0 00110800 10001003 01220002 11010311 01FFC400 15000101 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000302 FFC4001A 10010002 03010000 00000000 00000000 00010012 02113121 FFC40015 01010100 00000000 00000000 00000000 000001FF C4001611 01010100 00000000 00000000 00000000 110001FF DA000C03 01000211 0311003F 00AEE761 F21BD522 855D043C 82C848B1 DCBF**FFD9** FEFEFAFE FEFEFE0F
```

Известно, что файл с расширением .jpeg начинается с последовательности байт FF D8 и заканчивается на FF D9.
В буфер я записываю последовательность байт с FF D8 и до FF D9 включительно. Как создать новый файл я знаю, но при записи данных в него из буфера получается обычный текстовый файл. 
Как в записать в него именно последовательность байт, а не строку с символами?

Comment: Я вот не понял вопрос. Отправленный клиентом JPEG-файл записывается в файловую систему всего одной строчкой: `req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('...здесь абсолютный путь до файла/file.jpg'))`. И зачем мне при этом знать, с каких октетов он начинается и какими заканчивается?

Comment: Если обратить внимание, то в начале и в конце файла имеются случайные последовательности байт, мне необходимо от них избавиться и на выходе получить новый исправленный файл.

Comment: Как именно вы записываете файл? Есть чувство, что вы делаете это не правильно.

Comment: И ещё бы узнать, как вы получаете файл от клиента

Comment: @ЮрийПирогов Знать это необходимо по причине того, что как раз перед созданием нового файла нужно отредактировать входящие данные, а иначе на выходе мы получим файл с нужным расширением, но нечитаемый (файл должен начинаться с ```FF D8```).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev ```fs.readFile('./data/google.jpeg', function(err, data){if(err){console.error(err);}else{ console.log(data);})``` В Buffer показывает набор байт, все отлично. Как мне потом отрезать, к примеру, первые 8 байт?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev ```fs.writeFile("file.tmp", res, function(err){if(err)throw err;})``` - вот так записываю

Comment: Так ведь не понятно, почему файл-то испорчен, откуда там клиент надыбал лишние байты?

Comment: @AndMac, пожалуйста, добавьте в _сам вопрос_ [mcve] кода, который не работает

Comment: @ЮрийПирогов Это уже тонкости специальности) Но лишние байты будут всегда.

Comment: Стоп-стоп. У вас файл приходит в виде вот этих вот буковок?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, нет, файл как файл.

Answer (score 0):

### Всем спасибо!

Проблема заключалась в момент формирования нового буфера, содержащего hex-запись искомого изображения(буфер, видимо, вопспринимался как массив, из-за этого не работало смещение). Вот рабочий вариант:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./data/google.jpeg', function (err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
else {
    var start,
        stop;
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] == 0xff) {
            if (data[i + 1] == 0xd8) {
                start = i;
            } else {
                if (data[i + 1] == 0xd9) {
                    stop = i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var buf = Buffer.from(data.buffer, start, stop);
}
fs.writeFile("./data/file.jpeg", buf, function(err){if(err)throw err;})
});
```